# Using small kernel size for CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Is there any publication or research article from Zimmerman et al. or any other scholar in which it is mentioned that using small kernel size i.e. 3x3 achieve better results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to this article:

[Simonyan K. and Zissermann, A. (2014): *Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Large-Scale Image Recognition.*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556)

Arguably, their main message is not that small kernels are better, rather demonstrating that the depth of the network is much more important than the size of the kernels. Also, they accredit the idea of using small kernels to [Cireşan, D. C. *et al.* (2011): *Flexible, High Performance Convolutional
Neural Networks for Image Classification*](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/ijcai2011.pdf), however, this work performs no thorough comparison of effects of using small kernel size.

Comment: I want to cite the Simonyan's paper but the citation is available in arXiv preprint arXiv. Isn't should have with journal or conference name?